# ¿Expresiónes regulares y patrones de búsqueda en perl?

Tags: perl

Estoy creando un script es Perl para saber si una variable contiene una determinada palabra al final de la cadena, este es el código:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $palabra = "Hello World";
if($palabra =~/$World/){
print "True";
}
```

Al ejecutarlo me genera el siguiente error:
Global symbol "$World" requires explícito package name (dos You forget to declare "My $World"?)

Pero al quitar las librerías strict y warnings el código me funciona bien, porque pasa eso y como podría solucionarlo para usarlo con las librerías ya antes dichas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El ancla '$' debe ir en la posición en la que se le espera. Entonces sería:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $palabra = "Hello World";

if ($palabra =~ /World$/){
    print "True";
}
```

Si está delante de una palabra, Perl lo toma como si fuera una variable, `$World`.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias, y  en este ejemplo como haría: my $cadena=""; if($cadena=~/^$/){print "Está vacía la variable";}

Comment: Eso, o mirar por la longitud: ```length($cadena) == 0```